# I can't reach to the controller function using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, codeigniter

Here I have a ajax call in that I have included the url, but it is not going to that controller function, if I echo hi in that controller function it's not displaying. I don't why it's not working.

```js
$('#astsmtbtn').click(function()
    { 
     var chk = check_field();
     if((chk.length)>0)
     {
      var astid = new Array();
      var aststs_id = new Array();
      
      $('.chkTicket').each(function() 
      {    
       if($(this).is(':checked'))
       {
        astid.push($(this).val());   
       }     
      });  
      
      $.each($("#aststs_id option:selected"), function(){            
                aststs_id.push($(this).val());
            }); 
      
      $.ajax({ 
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo site_url('asset/asset_status'); ?>",
       data: {astid:astid,aststs_id:aststs_id},
       success: function(msg)
       {
        alert(astid);alert(aststs_id);exit;
        $.gritter.add({
         title: "Status saved successfully!!!",
         text: "",
         time: 2000    
        });
       }
      }); 
     }
     else
     {
      $.gritter.add({
       title: "Select at least one Asset in list!!!",
       text: "",
       time: 2000    
      });
      return false
     }
    });
```

Comment: If the problem is with CodeIgniter, then perhaps you could show your PHP code? I wonder if your route definitions are the problem.

Comment: Controller function? Huh where is that?

Comment: public function asset_status(){echo "hi";die;$astid = $this->input->post("astid");$aststs_id = $this->input->post("aststs_id");$this>asset_model>update_asset_status($astid,$aststs_id);
  //redirect("asset/index");
 }

Comment: what do you see in network tab? have you tried to debug ?